# Replicate least squares regression to check consistency of estimation and prediction with truth

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, least-squares

Here is the problem: Five observations on `Y` are to be taken when `X = 4, 8, 12, 16, 20`, respectively. The true regression function is `E(y) = 20 + 4X`, and the `ei` are independent `N(O, 25)`.

1. Generate five normal random numbers, with mean 0 and variance 25. Consider these random numbers as the error terms for the five `Y` observations at `X = 4,8, 12, 16, 20` and calculate `Y1`, `Y2` , `Y3` , `Y4` , and `Y5`. Obtain the least squares estimates `bo` and `b1`, when fitting a straight line to the five cases. Also calculate `Yh` when `Xh = 10` and obtain a 95 percent confidence interval for `E(Yh)` when `Xh = 10`. I did part 1, but  I need help to repeat it for 200 times.
2. Repeat part (1) 200 times, generating new random numbers each time.
3. Make a frequency distribution of the 200 estimates `b1`. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the 200 estimates `b1`. Are the results consistent with theoretical expectations?
4. What proportion of the 200 confidence intervals for `E(Yh)` when `Xh = 10` include `E(Yh)`? Is this result consistent with theoretical expectations?

Here's my code so far, I am stumped on how to repeat part 1 for 200 times:

```
X <- matrix(c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20), nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
e <- matrix(c(rnorm(5,0,sqrt(5))), nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
Y <- 20 + 4 * X + e
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y=Y, X=X, e=e))
names(mydata) <- c("Y","X","e")
reg<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata)
predict(reg, newdata = data.frame(X=10), interval="confidence")
```

Comment: Well, since you are tasked to "repeat" something, your friends will be loops ("for" or "while"). Or, if you're in for a thrill, something like "apply"....

Comment: or even `replicate`...

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping. @LorenzoBusetto, yes great suggestion.  I tried to make a FOR loop with code 'for(i in 1:5) {erep[i] = rnorm(1,0,5)}'  I don't know where to go from here.  My code randomly generates 1 number 5 times. What I need to do is randomly generate 5 numbers (with rnorm) 200 times. I'm stumped!

Comment: Hi June. It's not that I don't want to help, but that I fear at it would be difficult to you to understand how it works... I'd really suggest you to have a look to some free online "R" courses. Just going through the first "lessons" should give you a sufficient overview of some basic "R" programming concepts from which to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your code. You want independent `N(O, 25)` errors, but you passed `sqrt(5)` as standard error to `rnorm()`. It should be `5`.

We first wrap up your code into a function. This function takes no input, but run experiment once, and returns regression coefficients `b0`, `b1` and prediction `fit`, `lwr`, `upr` in a **named** vector.

```
sim <- function () {
  x <- c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20)
  y <- 20 + 4 * x + rnorm(5,0,5)
  fit <- lm(y ~ x)
  pred <- predict(fit, data.frame(x = 10), interval = "confidence")
  pred <- setNames(c(pred), dimnames(pred)[[2]])
  ## return simulation result
  c(coef(fit), pred)
  }
```

For example, let's try

```
set.seed(2016)
sim()
#(Intercept)           x         fit         lwr         upr 
#  24.222348    3.442742   58.649773   47.522309   69.777236
```

Now we use `replicate` to repeat such experiment 200 times.

```
set.seed(0)
z <- t(replicate(200, sim()))

head(z)
#     (Intercept)        x      fit      lwr      upr
#[1,]   24.100535 3.987755 63.97808 57.61262 70.34354
#[2,]    6.417639 5.101501 57.43265 52.44263 62.42267
#[3,]   20.652355 3.797991 58.63227 52.74861 64.51593
#[4,]   20.349829 3.816426 58.51409 52.59115 64.43702
#[5,]   19.891873 4.095140 60.84327 57.49911 64.18742
#[6,]   24.586749 3.589483 60.48158 53.64574 67.31743
```

There will be 200 rows, for results of 200 simulations.
The second column contains estimation for `b1` under 200 simulations, we compute their mean and standard error:

```
mean(z[,2])
# [1] 3.976249

sd(z[,2])
# [1] 0.4263377
```

We know that the true value is `4`, and it is evident that our estimate is consistent with true values.

Finally, let's check with 95% confidence interval for prediction at `X = 10`. The true value is `20 + 4 * 10 = 60`, so the proportion of confidence interval that covers this true vale is

```
mean(z[, "lwr"] < 60 & z[, "upr"] > 60)
## 0.95
```

which is **exactly** 0.95.